# dates format (or substring??) in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5 application where i need to take the month and the year from the input type month. i have stored these attributes in different columns because i have to search records depending on the year.I'm new to laravel and i'm wondering if there is any substring method with delimiters in laravel. i searched in the documentation but no luck.

This is the input where i get the month from:

```
<input name="month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />
```

The value that is posted from the above input is in the following format:

```
2015-06
```

And this is the migration file

```
Schema::create('reports', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        /*other columns*/
        $table->integer('month',false,false,'2');
        $table->integer('year',false,false,'4');
        /*other columns*/
    });
```

Also i am not sure if the above syntax is correct. I tried to put the int fixed size at the end. I'm using sql server with it.

Any help would really be appreciated, even if it's just a hint.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You say you want to concatenate but you sound as if you want to separate before inserting the input value to your DB. So are you trying to get some data from the database, month and year, then concatenate them or are you trying to separate them before inserting into you DB?

Comment: @haakym sorry my bad. i meant substring. not concatenate. and i am trying to separate them before inserting them into db

Comment: So you're trying to split a string before inserting into the DB? Have you looked at explode? If you have a string like `$date = "2015-10"` you can do `$dateSplit = explode("-", $date)` which will split it into an array, so if you access `$dateSplit[0]` it will give you year and `$dateSplit[1]` it will give you month. Is this what you're trying to do or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: exactly that's what i need. i have to write that in the model on a function though right? i'm new to laravel

Comment: Well usually youd have a controller with a method to insert it into your db you can use a model to do the insert via the create method. Have you got a controller set up currently?

Comment: yes the controller is set up and everything even the create method. just need to know where to put this. i also have completed the $fillable variable

Comment: Okay I will try put up an answer, you may need to adjust it though as you have no code up in your question, please edit if you want a better answer or make a comment after I put the answer up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of assumptions made here so adjust your code accordingly. If you don't understand something please leave a comment.

Before you store anything you need to have a route which your form will post the data to, you could do something like this for example:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('report', [
    'uses' => 'ReportsController@store'
]);
```

**ReportsController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // date should be the name of your input in your form, 
    // i.e. whatever is in the "name" attribute
    $dateInput = $request->get('date');
    // or you could do $dateInput = \Input::get('date') if you're not injecting Illuminate\Http\Request
    $date      = explode('-', $dateInput); 
    $year      = $date[0];
    $month     = $date[1];

    // I am assuming your model is named Report and you're using Eloquent
    \Report::create([
        'month' => $month,
        'year'  => $year
    ]);

    // finished so do something here
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**EDIT: to deal with multiple date fields**

Update html in **view** as so:

```
<!-- with the name value followed by [] it will pass value as an array, you can have as many of these as you like -->
<input name="date[]" data-month="month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />
<input name="date[]" data-month="month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />
<input name="date[]" data-month="month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />
```

**Controller method**

```
$dateInputs = $request->get('date'); // get the date input array
$reports = []; // this will keep what we input in our DB

// loop through the date input array
foreach($dateInputs as $dateInput)
{
    $date      = explode('-', $dateInput); 
    $year      = $date[0];
    $month     = $date[1];

    $reports[] = \Report::create([
            'month' => $month,
            'year'  => $year
        ]);
}

return $reports; // this is what has been input! YAY!
```

*Important point:* In the question you said you were looking for a solution for splitting the string from Laravel - now Laravel does provide a lot of helper methods as part of the framework and some of them are even for string manipulation, but I believe this is the wrong way of approaching your issue. You definitely should be looking at how PHP can help you do this as it's a pretty trivial issue and not something you would require a framework for, so please note that the explode method is a method as part of the PHP programming language and not Laravel. Perhaps you can do some research into why someone would use a framework to better understand the point I'm making.

Hope that helps!

Comment: another question. at `$dateInput = $request->get('date');` the name is generated automatically because the data are gathered from a table. any idea how to do this? is it possible to use id not name in there?

Comment: You have to use the name attribute because that's how submitting a form works. Is it the only date input on the form, if so could you do something like this instead: `<input data-month="month-' + meta.row'" name="date" >`. Hope that makes sense!?

Comment: there are multiple date inputs and if i change the name only the last row will be submited

Comment: try `<input data-month="month-' + meta.row'" name="date[]" >` then date will come through as an array with all inputs named `date[]`. Does that help?

Comment: this is the output i got from json `"month":{"0":"2015-06","2":"2015-06","1":"2015-06"},"value-0":"","comment-0":"","value-2":"","comment-2":"","value-1":"","comment-1":""` i dont know if it will work because this is going straight to the db later.. i left the other input values empty

Comment: this works. but instead of just one input i have 3 of them. all with dynamic names. so i have to modify that algorithm to get all the values. the problem is the date that needs a foreach in its own. any suggestion?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. Update your question with code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79866/discussion-between-haakym-and-xhulio).

Answer (score 1):

To split the year and month values you can use the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function.

```
$input = Input::get('date');
$explode = explode('-', $input);
$year = $explode[0];
$month = $explode[1];
```